# javascript does rendering objects offscreen affect performance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, rendering

So I am making a game purely in Javascript (A platformer) and i was wondering if rendering objects that are off the screen affect the performance, e.g

if i had a rectangle 5000 pixels long but my canvas is only 600 pixels long would it be better to leave it as it is or to create added script that checks if a portion of the object is on the screen and make new calculations for a samller rectangle that is only drawn on the screen. would this be faster? Or does javascript's canvas automatically do something like this to increase performance.

This is the simplified example however my terrain objects have textures which are tiled and drawn every 40pixels along the terrain object to prevent stretching and make the class more versatile, i dont know if having a for loop doing this to objects that arent on the screen will affect the performance but thought to metion it anyway just in case. I wont inclue the code but please request it if you need a better example :)

Comment: Memory is the big limiting factor, exceed the GPU memory limit and everything will slow down. Unfortunately each device has different setup and there is no way to test for memory apart from monitor frame rates. As for off screen render I have never noticed any performance drop and do a lot of off screen rendering, that said, I only really use FF and Chrome and sometimes Edge on medium machines with good GPUs

Comment: i only use FF and I ran a performance test on the code and using two terrain objects 5000 and 4000 long i got 30.11 fps on average and when decreasing their size to 1000 and 1000 i got a dramatic increase in FPS up to 57.25 on average. The code for this was: `code` Terrain.prototype.Draw = function () {
 var tileCount = this.width / this.imageSize;
 var x = this.x
 for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) {
  ctx.drawImage(this.img, x, this.y, this.imageSize, this.imageSize);
  x += this.imageSize
 }
};